# Rolling slope per minute

Tags: r

I have some sensor data. Basically, they record data every X seconds. In the case below, data is recorded every 30 seconds. I want to calculate slope - Change in temp per change in minutes. However, below gives me change in temp per change in 0.5 minutes.

I am not sure I fully understand the rollingSlope function, found it here on StackOverflow...
Thanks!

Below example is reproducible but some packages need to be loaded, not exactly sure which packages are needed anymore. EDIT - Added zoo package.

```
library(zoo)  

Time = structure(c(1636381674, 1636381704, 1636381734, 1636381764, 1636381794, 
                       1636381824, 1636381854, 1636381884, 1636381914, 1636381944, 1636381974, 
                       1636382004, 1636382034, 1636382064, 1636382094), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                  "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
    Temp = c(1,
             2,
             3,
             4,
             5,
             6,
             7,
             8,
             9,
             10,
             12,
             14,
             16,
             18,
             20)
    
    tester = data.frame(Time,Temp)
    
    tester
    
    rollingSlope.lm.fit <- function(vector) {
      a <- coef(.lm.fit(cbind(1, seq(vector)), vector))[2]
      return(a)
    }
    
    tester$Slope = rollapply(tester$Temp, width=3, FUN=rollingSlope.lm.fit, fill=NA)
    
    tester
```

Comment: The code you have above gives you the temperature change per minute and not per 0.5 minutes.

Comment: I disagree. First datapoints have a 1 degree change per 0.5 min, and calculated slope is 1. The change per min is 2.

Comment: WHAT IS SLOPE?? CAN you define what slope is?

Comment: "I want to calculate slope - Change in temp per change in minutes."

Do you need more clarification?

Comment: No i dont. But it seems you do. Slope is the change in y per UNIT change in x. So whatever way you calculate your slope, it will be PER SECOND and not PER 0.5 seconds

Comment: Did you run the example code. Obviously it calculates change in y per change in x, not unit x. And as the steps of x are 0.5 min, slope becomes change in y per 0.5 min.

Comment: well it seems you need to learn basic algebra and interpretation No one can help you because you do not understand the simple logic. Hope one day you will get it. 
 for example slope = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0) eg slope of 2 means its 2/1, slope of 0.3 means its 0.3/1. Always the denominator is 1 hence thats why is defined as change in y per UNIT CHANGE IN X.

Comment: Sorry, you don't understand the issue and the aggression is of no help. Thanks for your 2 cents.